# Add trailing slash when it's missing in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url, magento

I'm running Magento on Nginx using this config: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento.

Now I want to 301 all URLs without trailing slash to their counterpart that includes a trailing slash. For example: /contacts to /contacts/.

I've tried virtually all the nginx directives on this I could find, but to no avail. For example, the directive specified in [nginx- Rewrite URL with Trailing Slash](https://serverfault.com/questions/152805/nginx-rewrite-url-with-trailing-slash) leads to a redirect to /index.php/.

Which directive should I add and where?

Answer (score 14):

I've found the solution: I added the following line above the "try_files" directive in the "location /"-block:

`rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`

which does the magic.

Comment: Could you go into detail on the behavior of the regex?

Comment: @DanCat Something like "group of any number of non-period characters not followed by a slash"

Answer (score 2):

This is very, very tricky because you have to consider all possibilities in your URLs. Let's have a closer look at that configuration you posted there and optimize it while trying to implement your wish. I have to correct the complete configuration because it contains more than one security risk for your website (and continue reading after the configuration).

```
server {
    server_name    DOMAIN.com;
    return         301 $scheme://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    index          index.html index.php;
    listen         80 default;
    root           /var/www;
    server_name    www.DOMAIN.com;

    location / {

        # Hide ALL kind of hidden stuff.
        location ~ /\. {
            return 403;
        }

        # Protect Magento's special directories in document root.
        location ~* ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config\.xml|var)/? {
            return 403;
        }

        # Directly deliver known file types.
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpe?g|js(on)?|png|svg|webp)$ {
            access_log      off;
            add_header      Cache-Control   "public";
            add_header      Pragma          "public";
            expires         30d;
            log_not_found   off;
            tcp_nodelay     off;
            try_files       $uri =404;
        }

        # Do not allow direct access to index.php
        location ~* ^(.*)index\.php$ {
            return 301 $1;
        }

        # Extremely risky ... oh boy!
        location ~* \.php/ {
            rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
        }

        # Not direct index.php access and not one of those ultra
        # risky php files with a path appended to their script name,
        # let's try to add a slash if it's missing.
        location ~* ^(.*)[^/]+$ {
            return 301 $1/;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
          include          fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_index    index.php;
          fastcgi_param    PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
          fastcgi_param    PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
          fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param    MAGE_RUN_CODE      "default";
          fastcgi_param    MAGE_RUN_TYPE      "store";
          fastcgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9000;

          # Ensure it's an actual PHP file!
          try_files        $uri =404;
        }
    }

    location ^~ /var/export/ {
        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
        autoindex               on;
    }
}
```

### IMPORTANT! IMPORTANT! IMPORTANT! IMPORTANT!

I can't test this configuration, I've written it down to my best knowledge. Please execute `nginx -t` before attempting to `reload` your nginx and report back if this reports any errors. Do not, I repeat, do not test this on your production site and test everything you can think of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't solve my problem.